# iOS push notification alert with three buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would need 3 button on a push notification alert. "YES", "NO", "REMIND LATER". Presently, I Only found only Two button VIEW & CANCEL, Where we can customize the Names of those buttons, But what about the 3rd one? Can't we have it? Can't we have another button on the push alert?
Is apple is restricting OS to do that? Then Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [APNS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1), the only choice you have is between one and two buttons :

> **action-loc-key**
>
> string or null
>
> If a string is specified, the system displays an alert with **two
>   buttons**, whose behavior is described in Table 3-1. The string is used
>   as a key to get a localized string in the current localization to use
>   for the right button’s title instead of “View”. If the value is null,
>   the system displays an alert with a **single OK button** that simply
>   dismisses the alert when tapped. See “Localized Formatted Strings” for
>   more information.

Apple seem to have strong views regarding how UIs should look like, and they don't give developers much flexibility.

Comment: Check category parameter in APNS Dictionary which can allow you to do multiple buttons.  `{
   "aps" : {
      "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
      "alert” : {
         “body” : "Acme message received from Johnny Appleseed”,
         “action-loc-key” : “VIEW”,
      },
      "badge" : 3,
      "sound" : “chime.aiff"
   },
   "acme-account" : "jane.appleseed@apple.com",
   "acme-message" : "message123456"
}`

Comment: @VickyDhas, fixed JSON: {
 "aps": {
  "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY",
  "alert” : {"body" : "AcmemessagereceivedfromJohnnyAppleseed",
     "action-loc-key": "VIEW"
  },
  "badge":"3",
  "sound":"chime.aiff" 
 }, 
 "acme-account":"jane.appleseed@apple.com", 
 "acme-message":"message123456" 
}